# Android Retrofit-2 "Unable to Get String Array"

Tags: android, json, string, retrofit2

I just get started with Retrofit 2 so I got some problem... 
I need get String[] of "**syn**" in "**noun**". 
I tried but it returned nothing!

```
String[] s = response.body().getNoun().getSyn();
```

Thank you!!

> My JSON:

```
{
  "adjective": {
    "ant": [
      "bad", 
      "evil"
    ], 
    "syn": [
      "full", 
      "estimable", 
      "honorable", 
      "respectable", 
      "salutary", 
      "unspoiled", 
      "unspoilt", 
      "in effect", 
      "in force", 
      "well"
    ]
  }, 
  "noun": {
    "ant": [
      "bad", 
      "badness", 
      "evil", 
      "evilness"
    ], 
    "syn": [
      "goodness", 
      "commodity", 
      "trade good", 
      "advantage", 
      "artefact", 
      "artifact", 
      "morality", 
      "quality", 
      "vantage"
    ]
  }, 
  "adverb": {
    "ant": [
      "ill"
    ], 
    "syn": [
      "well", 
      "thoroughly", 
      "soundly"
    ]
  }
}
```

> API_Client:

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/";

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(SERVER_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

> APIInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("bZKyFPxTIi")
    Call<Example> getDataFromServer(@Query("indent") int s);

}
```

> Noun

```
    public class Noun {

    @SerializedName("syn")
    @Expose
    private String[] syn = null;
    @SerializedName("ant")
    @Expose
    private String[] ant = null;

    public String[] getSyn() {
        return syn;
    }

    public void setSyn(String[] syn) {
        this.syn = syn;
    }

    public String[] getAnt() {
        return ant;
    }

    public void setAnt(String[] ant) {
        this.ant = ant;
    }

}
```

> Example

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("adjective")
    @Expose
    private Adjective adjective;
    @SerializedName("verb")
    @Expose
    private Verb verb;
    @SerializedName("noun")
    @Expose
    private Noun noun;

    public Adjective getAdjective() {
        return adjective;
    }

    public void setAdjective(Adjective adjective) {
        this.adjective = adjective;
    }

    public Verb getVerb() {
        return verb;
    }

    public void setVerb(Verb verb) {
        this.verb = verb;
    }

    public Noun getNoun() {
        return noun;
    }

    public void setNoun(Noun noun) {
        this.noun = noun;
    }

}
```

> MainActivity

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiService.getDataFromServer(2);

        Log.d("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                String[] s = response.body().getNoun().getSyn();
                Log.e("",""+s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("error", ""+t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }



        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
 ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiService.getDataFromServer(2);

        Log.d("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                Noun s = response.body().getNoun();
                Log.e("aaa",""+s.getSyn().toString());
                Log.e("aaa",""+s.getSyn().size());
                Log.w("response",new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("error", ""+t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }



        });
```

**To generate model class:**

Use this link to generate pojo class : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

- Target language: Java
- Source type: JSON
- Annotation style: GSON
- Include getters and setters

Just download the zip and add this to your project.

Output :

[image]

Comment: Try my answer once. I know your problem is solved but this is the another way to do this. don't need any parsing in this.

Comment: Error when `getSyn().toString();` --> `[Ljava.lang.String;@f00fa57`
And `getSyn().length;` --> size: 9 while it is 10

Comment: All my model classes from pojo.

Comment: about the length, I got a mistake, you right!! what do I need to remove? I removed all code from the first one!

Comment: It connected to JSON and show correct length but it can't convert toString() .. same error `[Ljava.lang.String;@f00fa57`

Comment: @ThuanVo remove your old model classes and make sure they don't conflict and also clean and rebuild and then run. as you have changed model classes so may be android studio not getting it. As i don't get any error actually

Comment: @ThuanVo even removing .toString also i am getting output that you can try

Comment: thanks Your way is better, I think. I can get values directly now :))

Comment: Your way is what I am finding!

Comment: @ThuanVo Happy to help :) happy coding :)

Comment: Can I convert it to StringArray

Comment: @ThuanVo Yes you can both are the same actually. just need to change in model from list to array. but i prefer to use list. It has more functions and easy to use,

Answer (score 1):

impliment using this code

```
 ideaInterface.getPdfUrl("application/json",pdfRequestPojo).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            Log.e("strace  ","**     "+response.code()  +  "   "+response.message());

            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                try {
                    //  String result = response.body().string();

                    String result =    response.body().string();

                    Log.d("userloginreports","***   "+result);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONObject json2 = 
                    jsonObject.getJSONObject("adjective");
                    test= (String) json2.get("syn");

                    Log.d("userl","***   "+test);
                    //   Idea_Urban.getInstance().save_Logoutdata(jsonObject.getString("data"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),test,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    sentreports();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("s2233e ","11111      "+e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.e("stgghb ","5522222     "+t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks !! I used JSONArray 
-----
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONObject json2 =jsonObject.getJSONObject("adjective");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json2.getJSONArray("syn");
                        Log.e("length", ""+jsonArray.length());
                        String[] s = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            s[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
                            Log.e("value"+i,s[i]);
                        }`